# How do I get more honey, nets, etc?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

In Animal Crossing: Pocket Camp, there are certain spots that give you instant quantities of the local item - e.g. in Saltwater Shores, there are "throw nets" that allow you to capture a bunch of fish at once.  There are three types: a generic "Throw net" that the game gifts you a few of early on as a taster, and some premium ones that cost Leaf Tickets.  (There are similar items for the river fish and the tropical bugs.)

[image: Nets]

Having used the gift ones, I am wondering if it is possible to obtain any more of the low-power ones (presumably using coins)?  Obviously I can spend Leaf Tickets, but that's a lot of cash...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Not yet, at least**. There aren't any in-game mechanics for getting more vanilla nets/honey.

Answer (score 2):

You can now get additional nets, honey and fertilisers in the following situations

- Completing goals in fishing tourneys and gardening events
- Popping yellow balloons that occasionally show up on the map (I think higher friendship levels may increase the chances of this?)
- Occasionally as a reward for opening the game daily